# Using dir function in Matlab - how to get rid of `.` and `..`

Tags: matlab, file-io, directory, dir

I am using `dir` function to list the content of a folder but it gives `.` and `..` for first two folder. Is there any way to get rod of this silly process.

Can I use regular expression in `dir` function ? (if I can, it can be a solution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in solution, but I tend to do the following:

```
d = dir ('C:\');
d(~[d.isdir])= []; %Remove all non directories.
names = setdiff({d.name},{'.','..'});
```

The `setdiff` command removes the unwanted elements.

---

Another cheap way to get rid of `.` and `..` is using wildcards (Windows only):

```
d = dir ('C:\*.*');
```

Answer (score 4):

How about this

```
list = dir('/var/temp');
list = list(3:end,:);
```

that's of course assuming that the first two entries indeed are `.` and `..` which might not be the case on all OSes

Comment: The first two entries are `.` and `..` on Mac, Linux, and Windows.

Answer (score 2):

By the sound of this documentation, `dir` simply displays what gets returned by the operating system itself so I doubt you will be able to suppress it without doing some post processing of the list that gets returned

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/techdoc/ref/dir.html

dir does support the wildcard character *